# Is it mandatory for Muslims to choose the right sect or they ought to defend their current sect?

Tags: sects, wajib

In accordance with a narration, after The Prophet (pbuh), the Ummah will be divided into 73 sects, 72 sects will go to hell, and just one of them will go to heaven.

> Mu’awiyah b. Abi Sufiyan stood among us and said: Beware! The Apostle of ALLAH (SAWS) stood among us and said: Beware! The people of the Book before were split up into seventy-two sects, and this community will be split into seventy three: seventy-two of them will go to Hell and one of them will go to Paradise, and it is the majority group. Ibn Yahya and ‘Amr added in their version : “ There will appear among my community people who will be dominated by desires like rabies which penetrates its patient”, ‘Amr’s version has: “penetrates its patient. There remains no vein and no joint but it penetrates it.”

- [www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa6747)

So, is it mandatory for Muslims to change their current sects and choose the right sect? (If they find a sect which has more logical reasons or authentic narrations to prove its legitimacy)

As many Muslims are searching and discussing regarding different issues of Islam (even regarding various sects), accordingly many of them will encounter many authentic evidences which could indicate the legitimacy of some sects (or precisely one sect) in compare with their current sects. Hence my question is that:

**Is it mandatory for Muslims to select the right sect (when they see some authentic and logical evidences which mention the legitimacy of a sect) or they solely must defend their sects?**

**Or is it recommended (Mustahab) to change their sect and choose the right sect in the case above?**

Comment: All the narrations about 73 sects are inauthentic and have been disproved by Imam like al-uqayli in his book on weak narrations.  They clearly contradict the Quran.

Comment: Muslims, should strive to learn the correct principles not matter from which sect they're learning. That is the right sect, and should defend that correct sect.

Comment: As written, this is only attracting sectarian argument and debate.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that..., and actually the 2 major schools in Islam (Shia and Sunni) are not very different from each other. Actually both of the schools of thought are very similar.

The major differences seen between the two schools of thought, is of Jurisprudence. You have to remember, having difference of opinion on Jurisprudence does not mean one is doing a Sin. Even scholars within the same Fiqh (Shia or Sunni) may have difference of opinion upon the rulings of some things, a good example is that within the Sunni school of thought you have 4 madhabs (Hanafi, Maliki, Hanbali, Sha'fi) and in the Shia you only have 1 madhab (Jafri/Ithna-Ashari)...

The major thing we have to look out for is **Aqeedah**. It is Aqeedah which is most important. If one's Aqeedah is wrong then he will face problems. For example some people's aqeedah is that Allah has a body... But according to the consensus of all Muslim Scholars, Allah Does NOT have a bodily form... Thus, those who think Allah has a body, do not have the correct Aqeedah.

But if you research on Sunni and Shia, you will know that both the Sunni and Shia Aqeedah are very very similar... Hence it is not a question of Belief. Rater just a simple question of Jurisprudence.

Hence we should not say that, One is right and the other is wrong. Or Everyone is wrong and I am only right... Such talk leads to division Amongst the Ummah. And also leads to a tribal and egotistical mentality. Hence this mentality should be avoided.

We should look at each other and say... While Every person might not have the ultimate truth, but every person has some sort of level of truth and Haqq with them/ within them.

Answer (score -1):

Allah say in Aal-i-Imraan :

**

> (105) Be not like those who are divided amongst themselves and fall
>   into disputations after receiving Clear Signs: For them is a dreadful
>   penalty
>
> {وَلاَ تَكُونُواْ كَالَّذِينَ تَفَرَّقُواْ وَاخْتَلَفُواْ مِن بَعْدِ
>   مَا جَاءهُمُ الْبَيِّنَاتُ وَأُوْلَئِكَ لَهُمْ عَذَابٌ عَظِيمٌ}

**

A Muslim **does not** follow any sect, a true Muslim is the one who follows what is in the Quran and what Prophet Muhammed said.

A Muslim should not be "Suni or shai" that is not what our God ordered us to be.

Allah says in The Cattle (اﻷنعام )

**

> And, [moreover], this is My path, which is straight, so follow it; and
>   do not follow [other] ways, for you will be separated from His way.
>   This has He instructed you that you may become righteous.
>
> وَأَنَّ هَٰذَا صِرَاطِي مُسْتَقِيمًا فَاتَّبِعُوهُ ۖ وَلَا تَتَّبِعُوا
>   السُّبُلَ فَتَفَرَّقَ بِكُمْ عَن سَبِيلِهِ ۚ ذَٰلِكُمْ وَصَّاكُم بِهِ
>   لَعَلَّكُمْ تَتَّقُونَ (153)

**

Comment: We are not a site for explaining what is or is not a "true Muslim", nor what they "should" or "should not" be doing; we are a pluralistic site for *all* groups that call themselves Muslim, not a forum for debating which interpretation of Islam is "more correct". See also http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/275/22